# Making Subids And Postback Tracking Work

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am coding a Bounty Script in Php. (Reward Script),using open source code from Prosper202.Trying to track leads with Subids and Postbacks.I am not able to get this stuff to work.
Example.

I would like to append Unique id at end of url.
Like `http://google.com/c3={unique_id}`

Here Unique id needs to be generated randomly atleast vaild for 15 minutes and needs to be stored in Mysql database.

When Successful third party server sends postback in format.

```
http://watever.com/c3={unique_id}
```

We then need to compare both in real time. (this needs to be as fast as possible to avoid delays to end user.)

What should we use in this Case?

JavaScript to use for Postback or php?

And how to manipulate the postback in php script.

As i mentioned. This Script Prosper202 also have same feature of tracking postbacks.
But i am not able to extract useful code from it.

**Resources:-**

```
http://prosper.tracking202.com/apps/
http://prosper.tracking202.com/forum/6/21/tracking-subids#7848
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you need to do:

1) Create a transactions table in MySQL with these fields:

```
TRANSACTIONS
############
id - INT, AUTO-INCREMENT, UNSIGNED, NOT NULL
transaction_id - VARCHAR(8)
created_on - TIMESTAMP, DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
```

2) Create a conversions table in MySQL with these fields:

```
CONVERSIONS
###########
id - INT, AUTO-INCREMENT, UNSIGNED, NOT NULL
transaction_id - VARCHAR(8)
created_on - TIMESTAMP, DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
```

3) In your code, prior to sending them to a URL, you need to generate and attach a unique transaction ID (a.k.a Sub ID):

```
/**
* Generates [$length] character transaction ID's. Verifies transaction ID is not
* currently in use. If it is, function recursively attempts to generate
* a unique one. After 10 attempts, it fails and returns false.
*
* @param PDO    Database connection via dependency injection
* @param Int    Length of string to generate
*/
function generateTransactionId($db, $length = 8)
{
// Don't let this function get stuck in endless recursion.
static $recursion_count = 0;
$recursion_count++;
if($recursion_count > 10) 
{
    $recursion_count = 0; 
    return false; 
}

// Create transaction ID
$transaction_id = substr(md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)), 0, $length);

// Check to make sure it is unique
$query = "SELECT id FROM myDb.transactions WHERE transaction_id = ?";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array($transaction_id));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$stmt = null;

// If nothing found, we have a unique ID. Otherwise recursively find a unique one.
if(!is_object($row) || $row == false)
{
    // Reset recursion counter
    $recursion_count = 0;

    // Found unique ID
    return $transaction_id;
}
else
{
    // Recursively generate unique transaction ID
    return generateTransactionId($db);
}
}

$url = "http://www.google.com/";
$transaction_id = generateTransactionId($myPDOConnection);

// Add to URL
$url = $url . "?c3=" . $transaction_id;

// Do redirect to URL
header('Location: ' . $url);
```

4) In another script used to receive the postback, you will want to grab the Sub ID/Transaction ID via GET (or POST if you are so inclined) and mark the conversion:

```
$transaction_id = isset($_GET['c3']) ? trim($_GET['c3']) : false;

if($transaction_id)
{
   // Received conversion, add this transaction ID to conversions table
}
```

---

As far as realtime comparison goes, the only metrics you have access to is the point in time before the redirect, and the point in time when you receive the postback. You can see how many redirects you have done by checking the COUNT() in your transactions table. You can see how many postbacks/conversions you have received by checking the COUNT() in your conversions table.